# Why does lldb complain my class needs a conversion operator, even though it has one?

Tags: lldb

I have a template class with a uint32_t conversion operator

```
template<uint32_t NumBytes>
struct packed_uint
{
    ...
    inline operator uint32_t() const
    {
        switch (NumBytes)
        {
           ...
        }
    }
};
```

yet when I use the command `p (uint32_t)(a_packed_uint)` in lldb it says

```
error: cannot convert 'const a_packed_uint<4>' to 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') without a conversion operator
```

I get the same error using `static_cast` and if I try casting to `const uint32_t`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might be the `inline`, have you tried without?

Comment: Dave is most likely right.  If you instruct the compiler to inline a function, it won't produce an out-of-line copy of the conversion operator.   You can verify this by running `nm <binary> | c++filt` then looking for the conversion operator.  It's probably not there.  Calling an inlined instance of a function from within an lldb expression is not possible, there's no ABI for inlining...  lldb isn't smart enough to produce template function instantiations from the header files in your project, though there's been some progress made on this front recently.

Comment: Dave Lee, no I haven't. I will try and report back.